# Excel apply Function to filtered range

Tags: excel, sumifs

I work a lot with `SUMIF` statements but today need to basically create and `EXACTIF` function.

What I am looking for is something that could turn `AND(EXACT(FUNCT(A1:A10,B1:B10)))` into `AND(EXACT({A1,A2,A5,A7,A10}))` or in other programming languages there would exist something like `FUNCTIF(EXACT,A1:A10,B1:B10)`. Preferable I wouldn't have to use VBA.

```
     A      B
1    Hello  TRUE
2    Hello  TRUE
3    Bye    FALSE
4    Bye    FALSE
5    Hello  TRUE
6    Hello  FALSE
7    Bye    TRUE
8    Bye    FALSE
9    Bye    FALSE
10   Hello  TRUE
```

Comment: What shall be the result of `EXACT({A1,A2,A5,A7,A10})`? Not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Let me see if I have this correct.  You want to test whether all the values in A that are marked as TRUE  in B are the same value or not?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, I had missed one And function around the code that I will now edit in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula will replicate what you want:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,TRUE,A:A,INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,B:B,0))) = COUNTIF(B:B,TRUE)
```

It counts when the value in A is Equal to the first value in A where B is True and B equals TRUE.

Then it compares this to the count of TRUEs in Column B.

If they are equal then all the values are the same and TRUE will be returned.  If the counts are different then it will return FALSE.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I follow the logic. Will label it as the correct answer if there doesn't exist ay logic of the type I described above. For example SUBTOTAL works in a nice way to only choose shown values so it does this A1:A10->{A1,A2,A5,A7,A10} transform within its coding, but you cannot specify other non hard coded functions.

Comment: @Aruthawolf that is correct, but you cannot use arrays in EXACT() as it only compares two strings together not arrays of or many strings.  You cannot use `EXACT(A1,A2,A5)` as exact wants only two criteria.  Also EXACT(A1:A2)` does not work as it wants two criteria.  Even SUBTOTAL is very finicky about array type formulas and requires OFFSET or INDIRECT to fill the array.